# Apparent compatibility problem with NumPy or SciPy (Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, conda, conda-forge

So I've installed some packages from conda-forge (I'm totally new to this by the way) and when I try to run some script I get the error `Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject`. I already tried installing different NumPy versions with `pip install 'numpy==some.version'` but I kept getting the same error. My guess is that it has something to do with SciPy because of what the error prompt says, but I'm truly lost and I'd rather ask than break something. Thank you!

```
 RuntimeWarning                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~somescript.py in <module>
     12 
     13 import ephem
---> 14 import healpy as hp
     15 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
     16 import numpy as np

~/python3.7/site-packages/healpy/__init__.py in <module>
     61 )
     62 
---> 63 from .sphtfunc import (
     64     anafast,
     65     map2alm,

~/python3.7/site-packages/healpy/sphtfunc.py in <module>
     25 import warnings
     26 import astropy.io.fits as pf
---> 27 from scipy.integrate import trapz
     28 from astropy.utils import data
     29 

~/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/__init__.py in <module>
     89 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
     90 
---> 91 from .quadrature import *
     92 from .odepack import *
     93 from .quadpack import *

~/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py in <module>
     11 # even though it's actually a numpy function.
     12 from numpy import trapz
---> 13 from scipy.special import roots_legendre
     14 from scipy.special import gammaln
     15 from scipy._lib.six import xrange

~/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/special/__init__.py in <module>
    632 from .sf_error import SpecialFunctionWarning, SpecialFunctionError
    633 
--> 634 from . import _ufuncs
    635 from ._ufuncs import *
    636 

__init__.pxd in init scipy.special._ufuncs()

RuntimeWarning: numpy.ufunc size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 192 from C header, got 216 from PyObject
```

Comment: include the code that causes the problem & somebody maybe able to help